# Problems running first android app

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm going throught the tutorial on developer.android.com and I've gotten to the point where it wants me to run the program. I right click on the project in the project explorer, go to run as and click android application. The console displays the following

```
[2014-06-27 15:15:23 - myFirstApp] Android Launch!
[2014-06-27 15:15:23 - myFirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2014-06-27 15:15:23 - myFirstApp] No Launcher activity found!
[2014-06-27 15:15:23 - myFirstApp] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2014-06-27 15:15:23 - myFirstApp] Performing sync
[2014-06-27 15:15:23 - myFirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
```

If you need to see the androidmanifest.xml file, here it is

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I have my nexus 5 connected in PTP mode.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing activity tag like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    ***<activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.YourActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    ***</activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The app crashes immediately, but at least I know that it will open.